# Masking Objects with certain RGB values in Images

Tags: python, indexing, boolean, rgb

I am kinda new to Python, did a lot of MATLAB before and now i am struggling with the easiest things. My problem is the following:
I have an image of a synthetic scene. Certain objects have a predefined rgb-value. I now want to extract these objects. I declare the RGB values plus some offset and am thus able to create a mask that contains only pixels that belong to the object, everything else is set to 0 (=black).

---

For a brief example, lets say the color of the desired object in rgb-values is r=255,b=0,g=60 with an offset=5 for every color.
So far my code looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# read image_file
color_frame = cv2.imread(image_file,1)
# split the channles
b_ch,g_ch,r_ch = cv2.split(color_frame)
# mask the different channels seperately
color_frame[np.where((b_ch < b-offset) | (b_ch > b+offset))] = 0
color_frame[np.where((g_ch < g-offset) | (g_ch > g+offset))] = 0
color_frame[np.where((r_ch < r-offset) | (r_ch > r+offset))] = 0
# show the extracted image
cv.imshow('Extracted Object',color_frame)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

So far this is all working fine, but i would like to solve the "masking" in a faster/more efficient way. Is there a possiblity to assign something like all 3 restrictions in one line? Something like `color_frame[((b_ch < b-offset) | (b_ch > b+offset)) & ... & ((r_ch < r-offset) | (r_ch > r+offset)))] = 0` (this doesnt work though) or is my solution already the most efficient?

Comment: you can also use np.logical_and(b_ch < b-offset, b_ch > b+offset) instead of np.where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&` for logical and in `np.where`. So you can write:

```
color_frame[np.where(((b_ch < b-offset) | (b_ch > b+offset)) & ((g_ch < g-offset) | (g_ch > g+offset)) & ((r_ch < r-offset) | (r_ch > r+offset)))] = 0
```

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does not solve the problem. Python itself throws no error, but the result is wrong. If I use that for only 2 channels (e.g. red and blue), and add the green restriction later on, it works. I have no clue, why. Even extra brackets inside the `np.where()` to put 2 conditions together does not change the outcome. Strange...

Comment: I guess it's because your original code is in fact logical OR. So you can change `&` to `|`. :-)

Comment: Awesome :D works now! That was a stupid mistake, since I am changing the pixels I DON'T want to 0.